# how to use buttons from HomeView to select  tabs from uitabcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My Apps main view is having 5 buttons and I'm having tabbarcontroller with 5 tabs.So I need to select each tabs from each button action.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = i;
```

insted of i write the number of tab witch you wish !!!

Comment: helo...i am sorry its not working because self.tabbarController.selectedindex=1 means its in same viewcontroller but i need to bring tabbar view

Comment: i need to do a tabbar controller with 5 tabs...and same tabs is driven by a window contains 5 buttons....so mainview is 5 buttons and from that it will go coresponding tabbar when it selected

Comment: yes you have 1 tabbar controller and 5 tabs in it !!! You can access to every tab by writing self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0, self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 ....

Comment: i have 1 viewcontroller ok there i have 5 buttons...then i am added a new uiviewcontroller subclass and in xib i have added tabbarcontroller with 5 tabs...then from 1st view to access this tabs with that buttons so am writing ibaction on that .m file

Comment: am writing this ibaction in mainviewcontroller so self means its view r8?

Comment: yes i am having tabbarcontroller in second xib..no error is coming...only the buttons view is displaying...not switching it into tbbar

Comment: If no error comes what's your problem ? You must go when you press button you must go to second .xib and do action !!!

Comment: i am really sorry....do i need to write anythng in 2nd .m file for that tabbar...push to second xib means?

Comment: @interface tabbar : UIViewController {
 
 IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
 IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabbarcontroller;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabbarcontroller;

@end

Comment: it mean that you can use self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = i;  this

Comment: /
#import "tabbar.h"


@implementation tabbar

@synthesize window;
@synthesize tabbarcontroller;



- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
 
 [window addSubview:[tabbarcontroller view]];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

/
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
/
/


- (void)dealloc {
    self.tabbarcontroller=nil;
 self.window=nil;
    [super dealloc];
}


@end

Comment: helo....now its working i have completed that task.....now i need to insert navigation controller and table view inside every tabs...i need to put a back button in each tab to main view

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)selectSecondTab:(id)sender {
     self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; 
    [self.tabBarController.view setNeedsDisplay]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assign tags to each button in view as 0,1,2,3,4 and use the same action for all buttons as

```
- (IBAction)selectTab:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:[button tag]]; 

    [self.tabBarController.view setNeedsDisplay]; 
}
```